# Connecting table with html form in mysql

Tags: php, html

I have a page with an html form. The page is [here](https://adsler.co.uk/dating/), the form html is below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Registration</title>
</head>
<body><form name="reg" form action="connect.php" method="post">
<table width="274" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" 
cellspacing="0"><tr><td colspan="2"><div align="center"><?php // 
$remarks=$_GET['remarks'];if (!isset($_GET['remarks'])){echo 
'Register Here';} if (isset($_GET['remarks']) && 
 $_GET['remarks']=='success'){echo 'Registration Success';}?></div>. 
</td></tr><tr><p><div class="underconstruction">This page is 
under construction</div><div class="gddlabel"><td><label 
for="gddlabel">You're:</label></div><div class="gdd"><select id 
="genderselection"><option value = "1">I am a man looking for a 
 woman</option>
<option value = "2">I am a woman looking for a man</option>
<option value = "3">I am a man looking for a man</option>
<option value = "4">I am a woman looking for a woman</option>
<option value = "5">I am a man looking for both</option>
<option value = "6">I am a woman looking for both</option>
</select></td><td><name="genderselection"/></td></div><tr>
</tr><br><div class="af"><td><label for="agefrom">Age From:</label> 
</div><div class="af1"><select id = "agefrom">
<option value = "1">18</option>
<option value = "2">19</option>
</select></td><td><name="agefrom"/></td></div></tr>
<tr><div class="at"><td><label for="ageto" >Age  To:</label></div>
<div class="at1"><select id = "ageto">
<option value = "1">18</option>
<option value = "2">19</option>
<option value = "3">20</option>
<option value = "4">21</option>
<option value = "5">22</option>
<option value = "6">23</option>
<option value = "6">23</option>
</select></td><td><name="ageto"/>. 
</td></div></tr>
```

I then created a file in puplic html, my theme called `connect.php` and pasted:

```
$fname=$_POST['genderselection'];
$lname=$_POST['agefrom'];
$mname=$_POST['ageto'];
$address=$_POST['day'];
$contact=$_POST['month'];
$username=$_POST['year'];
$password=$_POST['email'];
$password=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
```

Then, I created an database and within it a table, like so:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 
memberconnect( mem_id int(11) NOT 
NULL 
AUTO_INCREMENT, genderselection 
varchar(30) NOT NULL, password 
varchar(30) NOT NULL, agefrom 
varchar(30) NOT NULL, ageto 
varchar(30) NOT NULL, day 
varchar(100) NOT NULL, month 
varchar(30) 
NOT NULL, email varchar(100) NOT 
NULL, year varchar(10) NOT NULL, 
username varchar(10) NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (mem_id) )ENGINE=MyISAM 
DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 
AUTO_INCREMENT=3
```

This created a table with the following fields:

`GENDERSELECTION, AGEFROM, AGETO etc.`

So far so good. However, when I navigate back to the page and enter data as a user would (my age, my gender, etc) several things don't happen.

1. Nothing gets saved to database when I press `submit`on form.
2. Form resolves to page which says, `this page does not exist`

What should happen is that:

Data entered is saved to database. 
On pressing `submit` user should be directed to page which says `registration successful, a confirmation email has been sent,` if all feilds correctly filled.

several notifications under fields if data has not been entered correctly.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Where is the database save function, all you showed is adding the post info to variables? Also PLEASE don't use tables for layout, before doing anything else learn how to write semantic HTML as it will help you learn a lot quicker even if it appears difficult in the beginning.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie what is the database save function code and where do I put it? Thanks.

Comment: So once you have all of the items you need to tell the database to save them. Search google for 'MySQL insert PHP example' and you will see you are missing a step to actually tell the database to store the information.

Comment: So I have three possibilities: object oriented, procedural and pdo. Which one?

Comment: PDO is nearly always my go to for people learning as it tackles a few security issues for you and encourages you to learn about bound properties. However you can pick any of these options and learn them initially. The key is learning the SQL statements, the different methods are purely ways to execute the SQL you write.

Comment: Like so? `<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDBPDO";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (genderselection, agefrom, ageto, day, month, year, email, usermame, password)`

Comment: `VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";
    // use exec() because no results are returned
    $conn->exec($sql);
    echo "New record created successfully";
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }

$conn = null;
?>`

Comment: hard to read in a comment but looks like it is right, you will have to try it and see. You seem to be on the right track now, if you are still struggling I would suggest updating your question or even asking a new one now. Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks. Where do I put it though?

Answer (score 0):

what you are doing wrong is that you haven't assigned names to your form fields, but assigned id, which is wrong, example:

```
<select id = "ageto">
```

should be:

```
<select id = "ageto" name="ageto">
```

what I also noticed is that you had a lot of things out of place, for example:

```
<name="ageto"/>
```

this is invalid and should be deleted!

Comment: I have names don't I? `select id = "agefrom">
<option value = "1">18</option>
<option value = "2">19</option>
</select></td><td><name="agefrom"/>`

Comment: Nope, the <name=agefrom /> is invalid. It has to be exactly like the id, attached to the select element!

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: A big difference, what you are doing right now is defining a new element called name, but my code is attaching a name to the select element, the other thing I noticed is that you don't have a code that actually inserts anything to the database, why?

Comment: An other thing to mention is that you had variable names exactly the same, i.e: password

Comment: Ah, what is it and where do I put it?

Comment: Variables should be the same?

Comment: Well, I would recommend that I send you some sort of a small tutorial on how to connect to database, do a proper form, etc, would you like that?

Comment: Yes please sir/mam

Comment: Can I have the full html code? I will do a quick tutorial here!

Comment: Full html is massive.

Comment: Can I have the start of the form and the end? Just until you reach </form>

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Registration</title>
</head>
<body><form name="reg" form action="connect.php" method="post"><p>Already have an account?<a href="#">&nbsp;Sign in</a></p>
  </div>
    </table>
  </form>
</body>
</html>`